# как с помощью sed,awk,grep вывести уникальные строки с не повторяющимся символами

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

Например
123z456z9r89 не правильная строка (в строке пристуствуют одинаковые символы)
123g456z9r8e правильная строка

sed 's/(.)\1/\1/g' выводит только через символ. 1212121

Answer (score 1):

один из вариантов:

```
awk '{cmd="printf "$0" |grep -o . |sort -u |tr -d \"\n\" |wc -m"; cmd |getline z;close(cmd);if(length($0) == z)print}'
```

где для каждой строки сравнивается длина оригинальной строки с длиной этой же строки но посимвольно-уникально отсортированной, и если длины равны то выводится оригинальная строка.

пример:

```
$ echo -en "123z456z9r89\n123g456z9r8e\nмама\nмария" |awk '{cmd="printf "$0" |grep -o . |sort -u |tr -d \"\n\" |wc -m"; cmd |getline z;close(cmd);if(length($0) == z)print}'
123g456z9r8e
мария
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе то что нужно.! впервые тут пишу не ожидал быстрого ответа. спасибо

Comment: если помогло то вместо спасибо лучше отметить как решение :)

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт для `awk`

```
BEGIN{
    FS="";
}
{
    err=0;
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if(a[$i]++ > 0) {
            err=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!err) { print($0); }
    delete a;
}
```

`FS=""` - эта переменная означает, что поля разделены пустыми строками, то есть каждый символ будет отдельным полем

`for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {}` цикл по полям, то есть перебирается каждый символ.

`if(a[$i]++ > 0) {}` в условии стоит постфиксный инкремент, поэтому `if` сработает, если в массиве `a` ненулевое значение для символа из `$i`. Если же такого индекса нет, то `a[$i]` инициализируется пустым значением, которое потом оператор `++` превратит в `1`.

Проверка:

```
echo -e '1234\nhello\n5432' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="";}{err=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(a[$i]++>0){err=1;break;}}if(!err){print($0);}delete a;}'
```

Печатает `1234` и `5432`

Comment: возможно ускорить процесс? мои файлы занимают примерно ~100Гб.